# Add NOW() and file name of csv into same mysql column

Tags: php, mysql

on import I want to put the name of csv and date of imported in the same column name,

On my code i have and error because $filename and NOW() cannot be in same column on thist code:

```
"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$filename' 
INTO TABLE $databasetable 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(name, firstname)
SET batch = $filename NOW() ");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved by using the mysql [CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function:

```
SET batch = CONCAT($filename, ' ', NOW())
```

Comment: any chance to change the NOW() format to day/month/year '%d/%m/%Y' ?

Comment: @Razvanhoratiu how about doing a basic google search for that? Formatting dates in mysql have been asked and answered here on SO several times.

Comment: Your answer is in your question! Use mysql [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) e.g. `DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y/%m/%d'))`

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly concatenate the $filename's value with that of now(). Honestly, I would do this in php, not in sql, but you can do this in sql as well:

```
SET batch = CONCAT('$filename ', NOW())
```

In php:

```
$t=date(DATE_ATOM)
...
SET batch = '$filename $t'
```